# Google Analytics custom dimension for anonymous/authenticated users

Tags: google-analytics

I use Drupal 6 and [Google Analytics module](http://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics). I'd like to have [custom dimensions](http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) to add segmentation for anonymous/authenticated users. I have added a custom dimension with **[user-role-name]** token. But I have a lot of roles for authenticated users, and then I get a long list of roles in GA data. I'd like to have only anonymous vs authenticated.

Is there anyway I could filter it with GA module in order to send only this two roles names?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't a role token that provides only a anonymous/authenticated role. The only way to do this (without removing all roles) is to [create your own custom token](http://www.taggartjensen.com/code-snip/drupal-7-create-custom-token-module) to use with GA.